# The .NET host uses all of my RAM in Visual Studio Codes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ram

When using Visual Studio Code the .NET Host that seems to be used by it just starts using more and more ram up to the point of where there is just none left.

It slows down the machine! This is half of my list:

Is there anything I can do about that?

[image]

Comment: @LeeTaylor yes, it slows down the machine!
This is half of my list: https://i.imgur.com/NxqSsMN.png

Comment: That's interessting, I have two (quite small) .NET projects open in VSCode right now and it has three ".Net Host" running. They are not listed under "Backgroud processes" though but nested under "Visal Studio Code".  Does these start for you as soon as you open the project or could they be leftovers from debugging or something?

Comment: Does your app have logic that invokes itself at the command line? I've seen apps that do this as a strategy for parallelizing work, where the initial launch kicks off 10 copies of the app with additional command line arguments to indicate which data to work with.

Comment: .net or javascript, which one is it? Or do you say that you're working on a js project, but vscode still launches lots of ".NET host" processes?

Comment: It is a C# workbench where unit testing is configured (but not launched). Only opening the testing extension created this mess.

Comment: I just started having this problem, and it appears to be related to the .NET Core Test Explorer extension.  It causes my machine to grind to a halt in under 2 minutes.  Simply launching VS Code triggers the cascade.  It seems when it is disabled, the problem does not happen.